# Missing Unicode characters in OS X

Tags: unicode

I can't see some obscure Unicode characters like *PHOENICIAN LETTER ALF* in the character viewer. On Firefox, it renders its fallback character, a box with numbers in it, instead of the real one. Does it mean I have to install some font or something to use it? How can I have all Unicode characters on hand so that I can type them whenever I want?

Comment: Being able to display obscure characters and being able to type them are two different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load, and use [Google's Noto Fonts](https://www.google.com/get/noto/).

You'll probably only need to use "Noto Sans", "Noto Serif" and "Noto (Color) Emoji" to get *almost* all supported unicode characters.

From the [FAQ](https://github.com/googlei18n/noto-fonts/blob/master/FAQ.md):

> As of September 2016, Noto fonts support all scripts/writing systems defined in Unicode 6.1.
>
> - For all major living scripts, Noto provides two weights (regular and bold) and both UI and non-UI fonts. UI fonts are for text display in UI elements (e.g. buttons, menus) that have a height limit.
> - For many major living scripts, Noto provides multiple typeface styles. For example, there are sans-serif and serif styles for Latin, Greek, Cyrillic, Indic (Devanagari, Tamil, Telugu etc), Armenian, Georgian, Thai, Khmer, and Lao; Naskh and Kufi styles for Arabic; and Eastern, Western, Estrangela styles for Syriac.
> - For many major living scripts, Noto includes both hinted and unhinted fonts: hinted fonts for Windows and Linux, and unhinted fonts for Android and Mac. (Note however that NotoSansSymbols is unhinted).
> - For historical scripts, Noto has unhinted fonts with one weight (regular).